# Facebook Login error app not setup

Tags: facebook, web-applications, authentication

Trying out facebook api and login is not working as expected.
I've copied the code on there getting started page here
I have tried the example on there page [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0)

my test app is here http://fbauth.parseapp.com/

Upon loading the page and logging in all i get is the following

> App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app
>   properly for Facebook Login.

Have set a site url and domain url on app settings to parseapp.com
Also tried setting the app public in status and review tab in app settings.

what else am i missing??

Comment: Have you added a Platform on the settings page for the app on developers.facebook.com/app/[yourappid]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your app is available to general public or not.

To do this,

1. Open https://developers.facebook.com
2. Open Apps -> select you App
3. Click on  `Status & Review`
4. Select the below flag as `YES`

`Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?`

then save. That's it. Problem solved.